# java.lang.NumberFormatException on parsing with commons-digester

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I get a java.lang.NumberFormatException, while parsing a xml file with commons-digester.

Not sure what it means:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "flickrmeetup rochester dan totheright 200701"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    ...
```

This is the complete error message: http://pastie.org/1708720

And this is the code: http://codepad.org/tw39paE1

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have passed `flickrmeetup rochester dan totheright 200701` to `Integer.parseInt()`  which is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() throws a "NumberFormatException" when the string passed to the function does not contain parsable int.

The string passed to the function is "flickrmeetup rochester dan totheright 200701". you need to pass a string containing only number values. e.g : "0" , "1234", "999".

Hope this helps.